# The Diophantine equation $P_1^3 + P_2^3 + P_3^3 = P_4^3$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, examples-counterexamples, diophantine-equations, cubics

Consider the Diophantine equation

$$P_1^3 + P_2^3 + P_3^3 = P_4^3$$

Where $P_n$ are distinct odd primes.

What are the smallest solutions ?

Is there even a solution ?
Or is there a reason no such solution exists ?

I looked at some parametric solutions for the diophantine but those did not allow all of the variables to be prime.

I was not able to find an easy argument with basic modular arithmetic or p-adic.

Notice the pythagorean triples, that are lower degree analogues, do not allow more than one prime ;

$$A^2 + B^2 = C^2$$

the solutions are positive integers of type $a(x^2 + y^2),a(2xy),a(x^2 - y^2)$ so never more than 1 prime.

At the same time, the degree 4 variant

$$x^4 + y^4 + z^4 = w^4$$

does have solutions that are all prime I believe.
So I wonder about this cubic case.

Comment: Did you code up a simple for-loop search (4 nested loops looping ➰ over a list of about the first 1000 primes) ?  That's what I would do.   Can't really be done by hand unless you're a human computer, because of distinctness + cubing makes numbers beyond what we usually know instinctively about.

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation3rdPowers.html

Comment: May be smallest solution: $631^3+461^3+193^3=709^3$

Comment: For the primitive solutions of $x^4+y^4+z^4=w^4$, two of $x,y,z$ must be even numbers.

Comment: @Tomita wow!  So, my code below was set to search for primes just below 631, or around 500.  Had I set it to 1,000 I would have found that one at least.  But it was seeming to take a long time to terminate, since each $\Delta$ in $N$ adds $O(\Delta^4)$ in running time.

Comment: @Daniel ,I got $p_4=(p_1^3+p_2^3+p_3^3)^{1/3}$, and checked $p_4$ is integer or not.

Comment: Tomita did you use Cantor's pairing function ?

Comment: @mick, I don't know about that.

Comment: More solutions where $p_4<5000.$

$(p_1, p_2, p_3, p_4)=(823, 691, 599, 1033),(2213, 2179, 103, 2767),(2447, 1879, 769, 2791),(2591, 1951, 31, 2917),(3541, 1667, 1399, 3727),(3631, 1783, 11, 3769).$

Answer (score 0):

Based upon this SymPy code, I would say that there probably are no solutions.  However, we still haven't ruled out incredibly huge prime number solutions, that are not feasible with SymPy.

```
from sympy import *

N = 500

P = list(primerange(2, N))    # Must make list in case generator object is only good for a one-off iteration;
# We'll be looping over this 4 times, nested!

solns = set()

for p in P:
    for q in P:
        for r in P:
            for s in P:
                if len({p, q, r, s}) == 4:    # Distinctness requirement met; see {} notation in Python, usually means dict, but
                    # here it means construct a set() object.
                
                    if p ** 3 + q ** 3 + r ** 3 == s ** 3:
                        print((p, q, r, s))
                        solns.add((p, q, r, s))
                        
print(solns)
```

Will print `set()` (empty set), meaning no solutions $p,q,r,s \leq 500$.

So next, you could try a C++ program which will (on this particular problem) run about 1000 - 10,000 times faster.  Or you can tackle the problem theoretically.  I am not sure how they do that in practice, but I've seen existence results of another but related type before.

Hope that helps.  I see you also have a prime number  addiction.  You're in a dark place now, but remember, there is light at the end of the tunnel.  But first you'll have to see through a few of these prime number questions you have to the very depths of prime number hell.  There you will find the reasons why they need the advanced Algebraic/Analytic Number Theory to even begin to approach such problems, while even those approaches fail!  Good luck with your prime number "adventures".

Comment: Yes I am in prime number hell. This is just the tip of the iceberg. Tomita seems to have found a case of primes !!
If you are looking for prime number conjectures let me know. My mentor is even a bigger addict and he has many.
Fun thing is they are not all like " for sufficiently large " but work for small cases too.

Comment: you can make a chatroom and invite me perhaps @Daniel

Comment: A solution of $p^3+q^3+r^3=s^3$ in odd integers must have $24|(p+q+r-s)$.  You may be able to use that to develop a faster code by excluding, for given primes $p,q,r$, prime $s$ not satisfying that condition.

Comment: I suppose we can verify that by mod 24 , but how did you find that ? @AdamBailey

Comment: @mick It's fairly well known that for any integer $n$ we have $6|(n^3-n)$ and therefore any integer solution of $p^3+q^3+r^3=s^3$ must have $6|(p+q+r-s)$.  I first learned of the stronger result for solutions in odd integers from a referee of my paper _Some divisibility properties of cubic quadruples_  which may be accessed via JSTOR [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/40378568).